# Including config file in PHP

Tags: php, configuration, include, configuration-files, include-path

I am developing a project where I am not able to include the files.

My Folder Structure:

```
--Myproject
-----Config
----------config.php
-----Includes
----------Images
---------------image.jpg
----------CSS
---------------test.css
----------JS
---------------test.js
-----Modules
----------Home
---------------index.php
----------Contact 
----------MyPage
```

[image]

I am trying to access the config file which is inside the Config/config.php in my Modules/Home/index.php

But I am not able to include the config file?

I tried:

```
1.
define("ROOT", __DIR__ ."/");

2.
define("HTTP", ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "localhost")
   ? "http://localhost/myproject/"
   : "http://your_site_name.com/"
);
<img src="<?php print HTTP; ?>images/banner.gif">

3.
define('PROJECT_ROOT', getcwd());

4.
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

Ref: [link][2]

5.
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

How can I like a config.php which is out side the folder structure but inside my project?

Comment: You should always use the PHP built-in constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when creating file path strings.

Comment: Once the file getting linked I will use all sort of built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `absolute path` which could be `/Myproject/Config/config.php` or reset your directory by navigating in upper level folder and then going to your require file `../../Config/config.php`

So you can manage to include with

```
include('../../Config/config.php');
```

As stated in `include` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter or \ on Windows, 
>   or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the current directory (starting with . or ..) 
>   — the include_path will be ignored altogether. For example, if a filename begins with 
>   ../, the parser will look in the parent directory to find the requested file.

Edited

Let's analyze include path. We are actually in `Modules/Home/` folder. te reach root level and can get inside `Config` folder we need to go two level upper, and we can do this by doing `../` for each level, so in our case `../../`. Now that we are in `root` directory we can navigate through `Config/` and get our desired file `config.php`. Now mixing all toghter will will have `../../Config/config.php`.

Comment: when I use include('../../Config/config.php');  I am getting the following error  Warning: include(../../Confg/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\www\myproject\Modules\Home\index.php on line 2

Comment: If I reset the directory it will become complicated as I need to give config for each modules :(

Comment: @Tomphp including the way I've shown here would not reset your directory, you will be in same directory as before, you will just include the file

Comment: Can you just edit your answer with my directory structure and show me how I can include the config file using the directory reset.. it confusing for me.. sorry.

Comment: I did include ("../../Config/config.php");
but still same error is it some configuration i need to do in my wamp?

Comment: @TomPHP Try to `echo getcwd();` it will tell us your actual path, please post result

Comment: the result is ""E:\wamp\www\myproject\Modules\Home""

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30174/discussion-between-fabio-and-tomphp)

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work:

```
include '../../Config/config.php';
```

Comment: no error: Warning: include(../../Config/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\www\myproject\Modules\Home\index.php on line

Answer (score 1):

What you **could** do, is include the following lines to your index.php path :

```
define("LOCAL_PATH_MODULES", dirname(__DIR__));
define("LOCAL_PATH_APP", dirname(LOCAL_PATH_MODULES));
define("LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG", MODULES_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config');
require LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.php';
```

---

What you **should** do, is put a file named `bootstrap.php` in your `Modules` folder.

Instead of the code hereabove, add the following code to your index file.

```
define("LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP", dirname(__DIR__));
require dirname(__DIR__) . 'bootstrap.php';
```

Now, add this to your bootstrap file :

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE SEPERATOR ALIASES
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("URL_SEPARATOR", '/');
define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("PS", PATH_SEPARATOR);
define("US", URL_SEPARATOR);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE ROOT PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ROOT", '');
define("LOCAL_PATH_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
define("HTTP_PATH_ROOT",
        isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) ?
        $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] : (
        isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) ?
        $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] : '_UNKNOWN_'));

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE RELATIVE PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("RELATIVE_PATH_APP", dirname(LOCAL_PATH_BOOTSTRAP));
define("RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'Lib');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ADMIN", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'Admin');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'Config');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_MODULES", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'Modules');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET", RELATIVE_PATH_APP . DS . 'Includes');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'Images');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'CSS');
define("RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS", RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET . DS . 'JS');

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE LOCAL PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
define("LOCAL_PATH_APP", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_APP);
define("LOCAL_PATH_LIBRARY", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_LIBRARY);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ADMIN", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ADMIN);
define("LOCAL_PATH_CONFIG", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_CONFIG);
define("LOCAL_PATH_MODULES", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_MODULES);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_IMG", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_CSS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS);
define("LOCAL_PATH_ASSET_JS", LOCAL_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// DEFINE URL PATHS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

define("HTTP_PATH_APP", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_APP);
define("HTTP_PATH_LIBRARY", false);
define("HTTP_PATH_ADMIN", false);
define("HTTP_PATH_CONFIG", false);
define("HTTP_PATH_MODULES", false);
define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET);
define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_IMG", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_IMG);
define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_CSS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_CSS);
define("HTTP_PATH_ASSET_JS", HTTP_PATH_ROOT . RELATIVE_PATH_ASSET_JS);
```

Now, you have a constant for both the local and HTTP variant of the most important paths in your application.

See [**the PHP PowerTools Boilerplate**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/Boilerplate) for a demo of this bootstrapping technique.